# Broadcast Receiver not capturing incoming message

Tags: android, kotlin, service, broadcastreceiver, background-process

I am creating an Android application which is capturing the incoming messages and saving them into a local database. 
All functionality is working fine if I test the app on a Nokia 8.1 or (Pure Android, Stock Android OS). 
In the case of Custom ROM phones like MI(xiaomi), OPPO, VIVO. The Receiver is not receiving the incoming message if the app is running in the background. It's working fine if the app is in the foreground. 
Any suggestions would be very helpful for me.
Thanks

I want to receive all incoming messages on every OS (Stock or Custom)

Comment: There's not really enough detail here to say much. Show us some code. What messages are you listening for? How are you configuring your receiver? What Android versions are running on your test devices?

Comment: Now Problem Solved. I forgot to add ReadSMS permission on runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I forgot to add Read SME Permission at runtime